# Incluir fichero de conexión a bases de datos C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, windows-forms, formularios

¿Se puede incluir un fichero con la conexión a bases de datos en C#?

Me explico, tengo 3 formularios diferentes y mi pregunta es si se puede incluir un fichero con la conexión a BBDD en cada formulario o tengo que poner en cada formulario estas lineas:

```
private static string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=pruebas;sslMode=none";
private static MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Es decir, lo que estoy haciendo en cada formulario es definir la conexión, pero no tiene mucho sentido ya que la conexión es la misma para todos los formularios, por eso preguntaba si hay alguna forma de "definir" una sola vez la conexión (conectionString) y utilizarla en todos los formularios.

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes por ejemplo definir la cadena de conexión en los recursos del proyecto (Resources.rex) entre otras muchas posibilidades.

Comment: Échale un ojo a Entity Framewor, de esta manera podrás enlazar la BD directamente a tu proyecto, y la cadena de conexión quedará guardada en un único archivo (`App.config`)

Comment: La idea que la conexión se la defina en la configuración de la aplicación, esta configuración generalmente esta en los archivos de configuración. Es la recomendacion general .Dale una mirada a [Cadenas de conexión y archivos de configuración](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files). Asi la puedes modificar sin compilar nuevamente (cuando cambies de entorno, por ejemplo cuando lo instalas en el cliente). INcluso esta seccion de configuracion se puede encriptar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, hay muchas posibilidades. Entre otras muchas, puedes plantearte crear una clase **SqlConnectedForm** que defina esas dos constantes.

```
public class SqlConnectedForm: Form {
    protected static string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=pruebas;sslMode=none";
    protected static MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

Ahora solo tienes que cambiar tu código para derivar tus formularios de **SqlConnectedForm** (en aquellos donde los necesites) en lugar de **Form**.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Me funcionó pero tuve que hacer la clase publica y las variables también públicas.

Comment: Efectivamente, menudo despiste. Al menos los miembros deben ser *protected* para que puedan ser accedidas desde clases derivadas.

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario que esa información esté en los formularios, puedes crear una clase estática con la información que ocupas:

```
public static class ConnectionManager
{
    private readonly static string connectionString = "datasource=localhost.....";
    private readonly static Lazy<MySqlConnection> databaseConnection = new Lazy<MySqlConnection>(() => new MySqlConnection(connectionString));

    public static string ConnectionString => connectionString;
    public static MySqlConnection DatabaseConnection => databaseConnection.Value;
}
```

Creas esta clase en tu namespace prrincipal, y va a estar disponible desde cualquier parte de la aplicación, no solo dentro de los formularios. Nunca sabes cuando vas a necesitar esa  información en métodos de  otras clases, aparte, si defines eso en el formulario le estas danfo chamba que no le corresponde al formulario. Aparte es thread safe.

La forma de usarlo:

```
 // si ocupas la cadena de conección:
 var cadena = ConnectionManager.ConnectionString;

 // si ocupas la conexión:
 var conn = ConnectionManager.DatabaseConnection;
```

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso lo hago de la siguiente forma: en la direccion del proyecto **bin/Debug**, existen un archivo `nombre_del_proyecto.exe.config` en el cual agrego las siguientes lineas dentro de la etiqueta `<configuration>`:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CharityManagement" connectionString="User ID=root; Password=; Host=localhost; Port=3306; Database=ventas;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

posterior a esto agrego la referencia de `System.Configuration.dll` y luego creo la clase de conexion:

```
class Conexion
{
    public static string Cn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CharityManagement"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Posterior a esto puedes utilizar la conexion en el lugar que desees de la siguiente forma:

```
MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
```

Un ejemplo basico seria dentro de una funcion:

```
    internal static bool Insertar(MUsuario objeto, facturacion.Vistas.VUsuario form)
    {
        MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
        try
        {
            SqlCon.Open();
            string query001 = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(nombre,ci,direccion,telefono,tipo,estado,cuenta,password) Values(@nombre,@ci,@direccion,@telefono,@tipo,@estado,@cuenta,@password)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query001, SqlCon);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", objeto.nombre);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ci", objeto.ci);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", objeto.direccion);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", objeto.telefono);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", objeto.tipo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", objeto.estado);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuenta", objeto.cuenta);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", objeto.contraseña);


            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                ToastNotification.Show(form, "Usuario Creada Correctamente", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.ok, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Green), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                SqlCon.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ToastNotification.Show(form, "Usuario no pudo ser Creada", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                SqlCon.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            ToastNotification.Show(form, e.Message, global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopLeft));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Este forma de hacerlo me alivia bastante cuando el proyecto es bastante grande.